# Cannot find -lpython2 : MatCaffe installation error

Tags: python, matlab, cmake, caffe, matcaffe

During the build of MatCaffe (Matlab wrapper of Caffe), I face the following error :

```
[ 96%] Built target convert_mnist_data
[ 96%] Built target convert_mnist_siamese_data
[ 98%] Built target pycaffe
[100%] Building Matlab interface: /home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64
Building with 'g++'.
Warning: You are using gcc version '4.8.2'. The version of gcc is not supported. The version currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'. For a list of currently supported compilers see: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release.
Warning: You are using gcc version '4.8.2-19ubuntu1)'. The version of gcc is not supported. The version currently supported with MEX is '4.7.x'. For a list of currently supported compilers see: http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release.
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython2
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make[2]: *** [../matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64] Error 255
make[1]: *** [matlab/CMakeFiles/matlab.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

On closer examination I found using following command that the following file is responsible for the above error :

```
 grep -rnw "./" -e "-lpython2"
```

It revealed to me the following :

```
./matlab/CMakeFiles/matlab.dir/build.make:53:   cd /home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/build/matlab && /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/mex -output /home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.mexa64 /home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/matlab/+caffe/private/caffe_.cpp -DCPU_ONLY -DWITH_PYTHON_LAYER -DGTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE -I/home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/src -I/usr/include -I/home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/build/external/glog-install/include -I/home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/build/external/gflags-install/include -I/home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/build/include -I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/home/trunks/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/include -I/home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/build -L/home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/build/lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/build/external/gflags-install/lib -L/home/trunks/Downloads/caffe-master/build/external/glog-install/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -lcaffe -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread -lgflags -lglog -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -llmdb -lleveldb -lsnappy -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopenblas -lpython2 -lboost_python -lprotobuf
```

So, I changed the corresponding -lpython2 to -lpython2.7 with the hope of resolving the problem. But to no yield.

I also tried the following :

1. Delete the CMakeCache.txt and doing the make. But it did not work.
2. I edited the default CMakeLists.txt file in /cmake-master, to change some default settings. I found that the default python version setting in the CMakeLists.txt in Caffe is 2 .

   //Specify which python version to use
       python_version:STRING=2.7

I changed it to 2 , and repeated the whole configure-generate-make process in a fresh build folder. But to no yield. Everytime the same matlab/build.make file shows -lpython2 , and changing that to 2.7 directly does not yield.

3. I tried to look into matlab/build.make file but could not find anything over there which I could directly connect with this error.

Any solid help would be deeply appreciated. I use MATLAB 2014a, on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4):

This is because of a bug in `caffe_parse_linker_libs` function in Utils.cmake which converts something like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so` to `-lpython2`

This can be fixed by **replacing** (in cmake/Utils.cmake)

```
elseif(IS_ABSOLUTE ${lib})
  get_filename_component(name_we ${lib} NAME_WE)
  get_filename_component(folder  ${lib} PATH)

  string(REGEX MATCH "^lib(.*)" __match ${name_we})
  list(APPEND libflags -l${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
  list(APPEND folders    ${folder})
else()
```

**with**

```
elseif(IS_ABSOLUTE ${lib})
  get_filename_component(folder  ${lib} PATH)
  get_filename_component(filename ${lib} NAME)
  string(REGEX REPLACE "\\.[^.]*$" "" filename_without_shortest_ext ${filename})

  string(REGEX MATCH "^lib(.*)" __match ${filename_without_shortest_ext})
  list(APPEND libflags -l${CMAKE_MATCH_1})
  list(APPEND folders    ${folder})
else()
```

The updated function correctly converts something like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so` to `-lpython2.7`

Answer (score 0):

According to error message and command, causes it, it seems that python libary is installed at unusual location, so `ld`(linker) cannot find it in its default paths. As CMake script has found headers, it should also setup `mex` executable for work with library itself, but for some reason it doesn't.

The simplest way to make building package work is to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory, where you python library is located, and run `make`. If you want to fix CMake script, this [wiki](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tsyvarev for the answer. I found a rather simple solution. I just made a symbolic link (libpython2.so) which points to libpython2.7.so in /usr/lib folder. This solved the problem. libpython2.7.so was also present in /usr/lib so i dont think it was the issue of an unusual install.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In despair I just removed the `-lpython2` from `build-matlab/matlab/CMakeFiles/matlab.dir/build.make`

It did compile after that, seems that it found whatever it needed regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it seems that it roots in the unability of Cmake to get different versions of python, such as "libpython.so.1.0". I changed my CMakeCache.txt file to "libpython.so" and the problem solved. It is not only for python, I had this issue with my "cudnn" as well, and this solution fixed that.